# Finding intersection of two function using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, intersection

I used the following to graph my two functions:

```
p1 = Plot[100 t^2*Sin[Sqrt[t]], {t, 0, 7}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 5000}]
p2 = Plot[Piecewise[{{250, 0 <= t < 3}, {2000, 3 < t <= 7}}], {t, 0, 7}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 5000}]
```

I can not figure out how to find the intersection of the graph, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FindRoot` with initial guesses observed from the plots.

```
sol = FindRoot[100 t^2*Sin[Sqrt[t]] == 250, {t, 2}];
t1 = t /. sol
```

> 1.61743

```
sol = FindRoot[100 t^2*Sin[Sqrt[t]] == 2000, {t, 5}];
t2 = t /. sol
```

> 5.07622

```
y = With[{t = 3}, 100 t^2*Sin[Sqrt[t]]];

p1 = Plot[100 t^2*Sin[Sqrt[t]], {t, 0, 7}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 5000}];
p2 = Plot[Piecewise[{{250, 0 <= t < 3}, {2000, 3 < t <= 7}}], {t, 0, 7},
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 5000}, Exclusions -> None];

Show[p1, p2, ListPlot[{{t1, 250}, {t2, 2000}, {3, y}}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03]]]
```

[image]